# Checking for existing JSON obj loaded inline via server to determine if the factory should make a call to get the same obj if it doesn't yet exist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a Angular app that should use either a freshly loaded JSON object via the sever (on page load), or in some cases, the app will need to request the same JSON object (on page load) from the server if the obj doesn't exist.

Using a service/factory, how would one go about checking if the JSON obj exists on the page? If it does, the app would then use that data and inject it into the controller. If it doesn't exist, the app would reach out to the server and request it.

For example:

```
var data = {item1: foo, item2: foo, item3: foo}
```

Let's say that exists on page load. Angular would then use the `data` var as the base to build the model. But if it doesn't, it would call the server, get the same obj and use that as its base.

Although I'm fairly new to Angular, I've read/written enough to know how to make AJAX requests and properly bind the returned data. In this case, I guess I'm trying to find out what would be a proper way to check for data and figure out if it exists in order to determine if a call should be made when the app runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$cacheFactory` to create a cache singleton and then cache the data you retrieve from the API.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('cache', function ($cacheFactory) {
    var cache = $cacheFactory('myCache');
    return cache;
});

app.factory('myFactory', function (cache) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            if (cache.get('mydata') !== undefined) {
                console.log('from cache');
            } else {
                cache.put('mydata', {
                    item1: 'foo',
                    item2: 'foo'
                });
                console.log('new push');
            }
            return cache.get('mydata');
        }
    }
});

function Ctrl($scope, myFactory) {
    myFactory.getData() // new push
    myFactory.getData() // from cache
    myFactory.getData() // from cache
}
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GVBWA/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Your reply sent me on an hour long journey in learning how powerful caching in angular can be and stumbled on things like:

http://pseudobry.com/power-up-%24http.html

and

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5820507

Once again, thanks a lot, this will really get me going in understanding how I can start my app early on with caching instead of going backwards when the app becomes sluggish due to the constant request of data.